# How to have variable value as an array within an array without it being a pointer? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array within an array, and I can call its values just fine. However, whenever I try to change the value of something in the second array it changes it for all of the arrays in the first array.

```py
for yAxis in range(len(g.WORLD)):
    if yAxis == yPos:
        yRay = g.WORLD[yAxis]
        print("=====")
        print(yAxis)
        print(yPos)
        print("====")
        for xAxis in range(len(yRay)):
            if xAxis == xPos:
                print("-------")
                print(xAxis)
                print(xPos)
                print(yRay)
                print("-------")
                yRay[xPos] = 1
```

This does the same thing

```py
 g.WORLD[yAxis][xAxis] = 1
```

Comment: How are you creating the lists in the first place? Something like `[[]] * width`?

Comment: Would you perhaps define the objects that you are using and describe better your input / output / expected output (in other words: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mre)). Apparently, most people here assume you are using a Python `list`, but this is not explicitly indicated.

Comment: Also note that `yRay` is just a reference to `g.WORLD[yAxis]` and that `id(yRay) == id(g.WORLD[yAxis])`

Answer (score 0):

You are likely creating your array as something like

```py
arr = []
bigArr = [arr,arr,arr]
```

This causes all the arrays to become linked. Use `bigArr = [list(arr),list(arr),list(arr)]` to create separate objects.

Comment: SImple check is to print `id(bigArr[0])` and `id(bigArr[1])` etc. to check if they are the same object.

Comment: I'm actually appending to the array within a for loop. Is that solution possible with the `.append()` function?

Comment: What is your actual code in the loop